# Find nearest vector to point

Tags: postgis

Is there any better way how to find vector nearest to point then this:

```
select gid,ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT($x $y)',4326),cr_2po_4pgr.the_geom)
as d from cr_2po_4pgr order by d limit 1
```

Sometime i have feeling that this is looking for nearest start/end point and not vector itself.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what your requirements are. I suspect that ST_Distance does determine distance by finding the nearest point ([see illustrations in ST_ClosestPoint](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_ClosestPoint.html)). If you'd rather define the "nearest" feature as that for which **all points on the feature** are closer than the closest point of any other feature, your situation is complicated. You could try using [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_DWithin.html) or defining a tolerance, buffering your features, and checking for containment.

Comment: It is simple, i have a gps point and i want to find road nearest to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PostGIS 2.0+, assuming you have built a spatial index and are using the geometry type:

```
WITH roads_maybe AS (
  SELECT * FROM roads 
  ORDER BY geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($x, $y), $srid) 
  LIMIT 50
)
SELECT * FROM roads_maybe
ORDER BY ST_Distance(geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($x, $y), $srid))
LIMIT 1;
```

The first clause does an index-assisted ordering to get a set of candidate nearest segments, and the second pulls the actually nearest segment from that collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use select by location that can be helpful for you to specify distances, unless you really wanna do it using python.